# Machine learning and Condensed Matter Physics

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, phase-transition, ising-model

What is the state of art of the use of Machine Learning algorithms in Condensed Matter Physics and Phase transitioning? Is there any promising result that lead us to think this is a good way to pursue?

I already know Perimeter Institute published a [famous paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys4035) in which they attempted (and succeeded) to apply Machine Learning ideas to Phase transitioning, but I'm wondering if it's only an oasy into a desert or if there are really theoretical groups trying to develop this ideas.

Answer (score 3):

The other big result that I'm familiar with is https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.216401. See https://physics.aps.org/articles/v10/56 for a nice overview.